# Swift: How to create an alert informing "wrong password" during user login (firebase)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authentication, alert

I have tried to add an alert to the login button informing the user if they have entered an incorrect password.  I added a showAlert.toggle to the signIn function but my syntax is wrong and XCode produces the following two errors:

1. "Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'alert'"
2. "Expected ',' separator"

Here is my ViewModel code:

```
 func badPassword() -> Alert {
    return Alert(title: Text("Incorrect password"))
}

func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
        switch error {
        case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
            showAlert.toggle()
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                    badPassword()}
                    print("wrong password")
                case .some(let error):
                    print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .none:
                    if let user = authResult?.user {
                        print(user.uid)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.signedIn = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                       }
                       }
                       }
```

Here is my View code:

```
struct SignInView: View {
@State var email = ""
@State var password = ""
@State var wrongPassword = false
@State var showAlert: Bool = false
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "mail")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(width: 325, height: 50)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "lock")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(width: 325, height: 50)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            Button(action: {
                guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }
                viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                }, label: {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

[image: ContentView screenshot]
[image: SignInView screenshot]
[image: SignUpView screenshot]
[image: AppViewModel screenshot]

Comment: You need to understand the basics of SwiftUI first, see the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/ 
and others like it. You cannot have code like `.alert(isPresented: $showAlert, ...` in a class such as 
your `ViewModel` class. This modifier is **only** to be used in a `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Alert** like this in SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
  @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    
       ZStack {
         
        }.alert(isPresented: $vm.showError, content: {
                Alert(title: Text(vm.errorMessage))
            })
     }
}
```

And your **ViewModel** class:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var showError = false
    var errorMessage = ""

   func showError(message: String) {
        errorMessage = message
        showError = true
    }

}
```

You can use **showError(message: String)** anywhere to show error. In your case:

```
switch error {
        case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
            
        showError(message: "Wrong Password")
        
        ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I applied your corrections and XCode did give one error message with two suggested fixes.   "Call to method 'showError' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit."  The first suggested fix changes to "self.showError(message..."  .  The second fix changes to "Auth.auth().... password: password) { [self] (authResult, error) in..." ...  both fixes which eliminate all errors, but don't work in the simulator.  No alert is displayed when I type a wrong password in an otherwise functional firebase email/password account.

Comment: @weekendwarrior did you write `alert(isPresented: $vm.showError, content: {
                Alert(title: Text(vm.errorMessage))
            })` in your View??

Comment: Yes, here is a copy and paste:  }.alert(isPresented: $vm.showError, content: { Alert(title: Text(vm.errorMessage)) }).

Comment: @weekendwarrior can you attach screenshot where you used `.alert...`

Comment: Yes!  I have edited my original post by adding a link at the bottom to a screenshot image.  Thank you again so much for your help!

Comment: @weekendwarrior can you share the whole code now with your view model class, your view to better understand why the alert is not working?

Comment: Thank you again for helping!  I have attached screenshots to the original post of all the code (Views and ViewModel)

Comment: @weekendwarrior first remove `@StateObject var vm = ViewModel()` in your **SignInView** and for the alert use `alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showError, content: {
   Alert(title: Text(viewModel.errorMessage))   })`, hope this will work.

Comment: @weekendwarrior please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it worked.